# How do I go build a Go GTK 2 app for Windows from Linux? Is there a Docker image?

Tags: docker, go, gtk, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile a .go file for the [GTK binding](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk) package Linux => Windows and can't figure it out. Tried going the route of setting up MSYS on Win but it was god-awful.

I looked for a Docker image but there is none.

````sh
$ ~/go/src/gui$ GOOS=windows CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH= CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from ./glib.go.h:4,
                 from ../github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib/glib.go:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:238:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-coverage.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-font.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-attributes.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango.h:25,
                 from ./pango.go.h:7,
                 from ../github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango/pango.go:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:238:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:241:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));```
````

Comment: have you gone through the issue tracker ? https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/42 https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+windows might help

Comment: Looks like on that second link the author mattn put one comment "AFAICK, your cross C compiler look header files on host OS.". So I will attempt to use that as where to look next for a solution.

Comment: i believe you should install the windows stuff and go with it. One issue tracker talks about it more specifically.